# SSL Pinning using Google Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp, certificate-pinning, public-key-pinning

I am starting my question by mentioning what I have tried so far:

I do not have certificate in my app, I am using SHA256 key only, Most of the answer on internet requires physical certificate in app to load it in keystore, I don't have that.

I am getting following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

1)[TrustKit](https://github.com/datatheorem/TrustKit-Android)  It need compile SDK 24 and up, but I have 23 and lots of Support library are in sync with SDK 23 so I can not change all of them, it may crash my app at some time.

2)[CWAC-NetSecurity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-netsecurity) I have implemented this in my code without using Android N security setup, I have also followed instruction given on git page, but not able to pass sslSocketfactory to Volley from it, it has example with OkHTTP. so it is also giving above error.

I have tried this with OKHttp's CertificatePinner by it is also not working for me. Same error. I have also tried to pass hostNameVerifier and sslSocketFactory to HttpsUrlConnection but same error.

```
JsonObjectRequestSolaire jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequestSolaire(method, URL, object, headers, responseListener, errorListener);
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(TIMEOUT, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    jsonRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    jsonRequest.setShouldCache(false);

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .certificatePinner(new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add("my_domain", "sha256/shaKey")//example.com
                    .add("my_domain", "sha256/shaKey")//also tried *.example.com
                    .build())
            .build();

    //HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(okHttpClient.hostnameVerifier());
    //HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(okHttpClient.sslSocketFactory());

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity.getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack(null, okHttpClient.sslSocketFactory()));
    requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
```

by using trustKit our iOS guy implemented and it is working for him.

Thanks in Advance.

Please share your valuable input here, so that i can understand this SSL pinning concept.

Comment: Is the used server certificate valid? Pinning means regular certificate check + pinning of the root, intermediate or leave certificate. BTW: If you have the sha256 hash and the domain name you can simply download the certificate fro the server any verify if it is the correct one.

Comment: Check [this link](http://blog.ostorlab.co/2016/05/ssl-pinning-in-android-networking.html) also.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#CommonProblems) also, might be the problem with CA.

Answer (score 5):

Use this VolleySingleton:

```
public class VolleySingleton {


  private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
  private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
  private static Context mCtx;

  private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
    mCtx = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
  }

  public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mInstance == null) {
      mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
  }

  public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
      // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
      // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
      mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext(), new HurlStack(null, newSslSocketFactory()));
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
  }

  public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    int socketTimeout = 90000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    req.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
  }

  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
      // Get the raw resource, which contains the keystore with
      // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
      InputStream in = mCtx.getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.trusted);
      try {
        // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
        // Provide the password of the keystore
        trusted.load(in, mCtx.getString(R.string.KEYSTORE_PASS).toCharArray());
      } finally {
        in.close();
      }

      String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
      TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
      tmf.init(trusted);

      SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

      HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
          Log.i("Volley","Verifing host:"+hostname);
          return true;
        }
      });

      SSLSocketFactory sf = context.getSocketFactory();
      return sf;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
  }
}
```